# Can you manage Server 2012R2/Win8 GPO's on a Server 2008R2 DC?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, active-directory

Having a little trouble clarifying an issue I'm having and google is unable to grant me a precise answer.

We have a new Windows 8.1 tablet that we are testing in our environment, this obviously needs GPOs (everything needs GPOs), I added the ADMXs to our 2008R2 domain controller using Microsoft's installer, but I'm unable to see them in GPO Management Editor.

I'm wondering if it needs to be in a Server 2012R2 domain environment to be able to use the new administrative templates, as I know you can't play with Windows 7 templates in a Vista/XP environment.

I could be totally wrong and just failing massively in some simple way, that is always an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you install the admx files you need, you simply need to copy the ones you want to your policy definition store so that the GPO editor will pick them up.
The folder location should be something like:

```
C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions\
```

Make sure you copy adml and admx files to the file location.

Comment: Do you know where the installer installs the admx files to?

Comment: Just do a search on *.admx files and you should be able to locate where they were installed to.  Same with the *.adml files.

Comment: Still not having any luck, I copied all the admx/adml files into the policy definition store (sysvol\sysvol\*domain*\ etc.), but I'm still unable to see server 2012/win8 templates in GPO editor.

Comment: I found out that you need to use GPME on a windows 8.1/2012r2 computer to show ALL the options, as GPME on 7/2008r2 doesn't understand the new options.